# How do I get the command line steps inside visual studio when compile and running?

Tags: visual-studio-2008

From the user aspect,we just click and see it run,but don't know what exactly is undergoing.

Is there a way to see **all** the internal processing history like:

```
> gcc foo.c -o foo.exe
> foo.exe
hello world
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Visual Studio outputs all the commands into a temporary batch file which it then executes, and you see the results in the Output window.

Try looking in the file 'BuildLog.htm' in your intermediate directory.

[More info here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b0bktkzs(VS.71).aspx).

Answer (score 0):

Check the Output window at the bottom docked pane inside your IDE. That should contain the full build output, including compile options etc.

Go to View menu, then Output window, or Ctrl-W, O.

Comment: Perform a 'Rebuild', I see the csc.exe command with the appropriate cmd line args.